# Delete record with query and inner join

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, join

I want to delete all entries from table PLTotals where the column Total_Row_ID matches the ID column in another table, PLLabelsAndFormulas

```
**PLTotals** TABLE

ID,       Total_Row_ID,      Member_Row_ID



**PLLabelsAndFormulas** TABLE

ID,       Company_ID,        Row_Label,       etc....
```

From what I understand I can do it with an INNER JOIN.

First I tried:

```vb
Dim accessQuery as string

accessQuery = "DELETE PLTotalsRows.ID FROM PLTotalsRows " & _
              "LEFT JOIN PLLabelsAndFormulas ON PLTotalsRows.Total_Row_ID = PLLabelsAndFormulas.ID " & _
              "WHERE PLLabelsAndFormulas.Company_ID = " & companyId
```

I get the error:

> Need to specify the table to delete from

I also tried:

```vb
accessQuery = "DELETE PLTotalsRows.* FROM PLTotalsRows WHERE " & _
              "EXISTS (SELECT [ID] FROM PLLabelsAndFormulas WHERE PLLabelsAndFormulas.ID = PLTotalsRows.Member_Row_ID) = True"
```

This doesn't give an error, but the records aren't deleted.

Comment: Is the table PLTotals or PLTotalsRows? Is Member_Row_ID a foreign key link to ID primary key? Or is Total_Row_ID the foreign key? Edit question to show sample data as text tables. Try IN(): `"DELETE FROM PLTotalsRows WHERE Member_Row_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM PLLabelsAndFormulas WHERE PLLabelsAndFormulas.Company_ID =" & companyID & ")"`

Comment: Or should that be `Total_Row_ID IN (...)`

Answer (score 2):

Consider using an alias to correlate outer level with `EXISTS` subquery.

```sql
DELETE t.* 
FROM PLTotalsRows t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM PLLabelsAndFormulas 
    WHERE PLLabelsAndFormulas.ID = t.Member_Row_ID
)
```

Alternatively, you can use `IN` subquery:

```sql
DELETE t.* 
FROM PLTotalsRows t
WHERE t.Member_Row_ID IN (
    SELECT [ID] 
    FROM PLLabelsAndFormulas 
)
```